# How to get searched data from second model through first one in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

The Profile model with (id | user_id | name) columns has user relation as:

```
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
```

the User model has skills relation as:

```
  public function skills()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class);
  }
```

the pivot table is skill_user with user_id | skill_id columns and Skill model user relation as:

```
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

How I can search for profiles that have a specific skill from the search request.

```
$profiles = Profile::with('users')->where('name', 'like', ''.$term.'%')->get();
```

but I get an error of not profile_skill table!

I can reach to each profile that has a specific skill through

```
$profile->user->skills
```

but how I can reach to these skills from :

```
<input name="term" type="text" />
```

I have tested users relation in Profile model but I get error :

```
    public function users(){
        return $this->hasManyThrough(User::class, Skill::class, 'skill_id', 'user_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition, you might want to try [whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence), which I believe is the simplest:

```php
return Profile::whereHas('user.skills', function ($query) use ($term) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "{$term}%");
})
->get();
```

Comment: hi Kevin, thank you, my problem was just the ('user.skills) pattern, also I found a shorter answer as:
return Profile::whereHas('user.skills', function (Builder $query ) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "{$term}%");
})->get();

Answer (score 2):

There's 2 ways to do this. The first one is to use eager loaded relationships and filter the resulting collections. The code is much more straight forward in this manner, but less efficient. This will check for EXACT matches, no LIKE queries. If you need LIKE please refer to option 2.

```php
$profiles = Profile::with('user.skills')->get();

$profilesWithSkill = $profiles->filter(function ($profile, $key) use($term) {
    return $profile->user->skills->contains('name', $term);
});
```

The second approach is to use query builder and joins. This should be faster but will return associative arrays instead of model instances. You can customise the `select` for the fields you need.

```php
DB::table('profiles')
    -> join('skill_user', 'skill_user.user_id', '=', 'profiles.user_id')
    -> join('skills', 'skills.id', '=', 'skill_user.skill_id')
    -> where('skills.name', 'like', ''.$term.'%')
    -> select('profiles.*')
    -> get();
```

It highly depends on your use case which one you should go for, and it essentialy matters when you get to high amounts of data.

Comment: thank you for answer I learnt something new out of formal documentation but I get an error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder:: filter()  and the second method send the error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '=skill_user.skill_id' in 'on clause'.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to add a get() call and accidentaly put a dot instead of comma. I edited the answer. I also tested both of these approaches on my own many-to-many relationship and it did the job fine. Let me know if it works for you now.

Comment: in both methods, can't get Profile data to show in @foreach($profiles as $profile) .... and there is no result!

Comment: The query I provided was for an exact match, i see you are using a like with a % operator. One final update for the 2nd option with query builder, if it doesn't work I will delete my answer.